# How to choose $a,b\in I$, so $ab\notin I^3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, dedekind-domain

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring, not necessarily Dedekind.  It has an ideal $I$, not necessarily principal, and $I\neq I^2\neq I^3$.  Is it always possible to find $a,b\in I$ so $ab\notin I^3$?

I know I $must$ choose $a,b\notin I^2$; however, for a non-Dedeking ring that's not sufficient.  What tools can I use, to make sure $ab\notin I^3$?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your goal. You mean you want, for any ring with ideal $I$, to find $a,b\in I$ such that $ab\notin I$? This is impossible in general, of course. For example, if $I=I^3$.

Comment: @rschwieb Can you give an example?  I thought if $I\neq I^2$, then $I^2\subsetneq I$, so $I^3\subsetneq I^2$...

Comment: No, you're right... I thought I had an example but then I realized what you said is equivalent. The condition you're talking about is only possible to attain exactly when $I^2\neq I^3$.

Comment: @rschwieb So, assuming $I^2\neq I^3$, how would I do it?

Comment: Pretty much by definition.

Answer (score 2):

If $xy\in I^3$ for every $x,y\in I$, then all the generators of $I^2$ are in $I^3$, therefore $I^2\subseteq I^3\subseteq I^2$.

By contrapositive then, if one assumes $I^2\neq I^3$, it must be that there exists $x,y\in I$ such that $xy\notin I^3$.

Comment: Is is possible that for all $x,y\in I$ we have $xy\in I^3$; but $I^2$ is principal?

Comment: @Alex Yes, if $I=(e)$ where $e^2=e$, for example.

Comment: I meant, with the assumptions in the question.  In your example, $I^2=(e^2)=(e)=I$.

Comment: @Alex In that case, what you just said is inconsistent with your new question. If "for all $x,y\in I$ we have $xy\in I^3$" then $I^2=I^3$, and that contradicts the assumptions in the question.

Comment: I do not see the contradiction.  If $I$ is not principal, then any $x\in I$ must also be in some other ideal $J_x$ (i.e. $xR=IJ_x$).  My question amounts to, whether it is possible that the product of any two such $J_x$'s contains $I$.  I was able to prove that the answer is NO in case $I$ is finitely generated; however, I cannot see an argument when $I$ is infinitely generated.

Comment: @Alex the contradiction is that you assumed both $I^2\neq I^3$ and a condition that proves $I^2=I^3$